# How to query the chaincode on Hyperledger Fabric Go SDK through targeted peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

In a hyperledger fabric network with multiple peers in an organization, Can I use Go SDK to query the chaincode through targetted peers from a particular organization?

I know I can query the chaincode using the channel package with the `*channel.Client Query()` function, however, I need to query through each peer individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way pass the targetted peers in `Query` call on channel client is by using the `channel.WithTargetEndpoints()` as a options parameter to the Query function.

An example to demonstrate this is:

```
req := channel.Request{
        ChaincodeID: chaincodeID,
        Fcn:         "invoke",
        Args:        queryArg,
    }

resp, err := client.Query(req, channel.WithTargetEndpoints("peer0.org0.example.com"), channel.WithRetry(retry.DefaultChannelOpts))
```

Comment: Thank You, how do I get an instance of a client to represent my channel?

Comment: Basically you create a channelClientContext like `channelClientCtx := sdk.ChannelContext(channelID, fabsdk.WithUser("Admin"), fabsdk.WithOrg(orgName))` and use that to generate client like `channelClient, err := channel.New(channelClientCtx)` .



Also, If this helped you, Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people
experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more
information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you, have you got any resources where I can learn to use the go sdk?

Comment: You're welcome, No man, There isn't a guide. however, github [docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/) is very well documented. That's how I learned most of what I know.

Comment: Okay, I've been reading and I'm getting there. So I've written a basic go application to query each of the ledgers. My network is in docker containers, where can I run my go application from to query it?

Comment: I keep getting this error when trying to declare 
 var mainSDK *fabsdk.FabricSDK
.go:227:23: not enough arguments in call to s.statsd.SendLoop
        have (<-chan time.Time, string, string)
        want (context.Context, <-chan time.Time, string, string)